# How the attribute disabled works on option tag in a dropdown select?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have the following code and i want to understand how the `attribute:disabled` works on an `<option>` inside a `<select>`!

Let's assume that I have a rating drop-down and I select options 5-stars (`★★★★★`). The javascript will capture the change enent and add the `attribute:disabled` on the selected option as expected, and a banner will be created!

Now when I delete the banner, the `attribute:disabled` is removed and the banner is deleted, also as expected!

**The issue:**

- Select 5-stars option
- Delete Banner (5-stars)
- Re-select 5-stars => ***cannot select 5-stars again (works ok if i select other option)***

```js
function handleRatingChange(selectElement) {
    createBannerFilter("Ratings", selectElement, "ratings-dropdown");
}
function createBannerFilter(prefix, bannerValue, dropdownId){
    toggleOption(bannerValue.value, dropdownId, true);

    var banner = document.createElement("div");
    banner.classList.add("badge", "bg-secondary", "m-2", "fs-6", "d-flex", "align-items-center"); // Changed text color and added margin class
    banner.style.width = "auto";
    banner.style.fontWeight = "400";
    if("Ratings" === prefix){ 
        banner.innerHTML = prefix + " : " + "<span style='color: #ffc107'>" + bannerValue.value + "</span>";
    }else{
        banner.textContent = prefix + " : " + bannerValue.value;
    }
    var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
    closeButton.classList.add("btn", "p-0", "border-0", "ms-2");
    closeButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    closeButton.setAttribute("aria-label", "Close");
    closeButton.innerHTML = '<span class="fs-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" aria-hidden="true">❌</span>';
    closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        banner.remove(); // Remove the banner when the close button is clicked
        toggleOption(bannerValue.value, dropdownId, false);
    });
    banner.appendChild(closeButton);
    document.getElementById("filters-applied").appendChild(banner);
}

function toggleOption(value, dropdownId, toggle) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById(dropdownId);
    var options = dropdown.options;
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].value === value) {
            if(toggle){
                options[i].disabled = true
            }else{
                options[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
/* FILTERS */
option:disabled {
    background-color: #c8c8c8 !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">        
</head>

<div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-select mb-3 ratings-dropdown" id="ratings-dropdown" onchange="handleRatingChange(this)">
                <option selected disabled>Ratings</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★★★★">★★★★★</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★★★☆">★★★★☆</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★★☆☆">★★★☆☆</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★☆☆☆">★★☆☆☆</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★☆☆☆☆">★☆☆☆☆</option>
            </select>
        </div>

<div class="row mt-2 mb-2"  id="filters-applied">
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The problem is that when you are deleting your banner, the 5-stars option is _still_ the selected one - so the `onchange` handler on the select field won't fire, when you simply select that option "again". Reset your select field when you remove the banner, so that the first option ("Ratings") is the selected one again. If you then chose the 5-stars one manually afterwards, it will be an actual _change_ again.

Answer (score 0):

As per @CBroe comment, `Reset your select field when you remove the banner, so that the first option ("Ratings") is the selected one again` so I had to add the following line in my else statement

```
if(toggle){
    options[i].disabled = true
}else{
    options[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
    dropdown.value = ''; //This will reset the selected value in the <select>
}
```

Here is full code snippet :

```js
function handleRatingChange(selectElement) {
    createBannerFilter("Ratings", selectElement, "ratings-dropdown");
}
function createBannerFilter(prefix, bannerValue, dropdownId){
    toggleOption(bannerValue.value, dropdownId, true);

    var banner = document.createElement("div");
    banner.classList.add("badge", "bg-secondary", "m-2", "fs-6", "d-flex", "align-items-center"); // Changed text color and added margin class
    banner.style.width = "auto";
    banner.style.fontWeight = "400";
    if("Ratings" === prefix){ 
        banner.innerHTML = prefix + " : " + "<span style='color: #ffc107'>" + bannerValue.value + "</span>";
    }else{
        banner.textContent = prefix + " : " + bannerValue.value;
    }
    var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
    closeButton.classList.add("btn", "p-0", "border-0", "ms-2");
    closeButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    closeButton.setAttribute("aria-label", "Close");
    closeButton.innerHTML = '<span class="fs-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" aria-hidden="true">❌</span>';
    closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        banner.remove(); // Remove the banner when the close button is clicked
        toggleOption(bannerValue.value, dropdownId, false);
    });
    banner.appendChild(closeButton);
    document.getElementById("filters-applied").appendChild(banner);
}

function toggleOption(value, dropdownId, toggle) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById(dropdownId);
    var options = dropdown.options;
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].value === value) {
            if(toggle){
                options[i].disabled = true
            }else{
                options[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
                dropdown.value = '';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
/* FILTERS */
option:disabled {
    background-color: #c8c8c8 !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">        
</head>

<div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-select mb-3 ratings-dropdown" id="ratings-dropdown" onchange="handleRatingChange(this)">
                <option selected disabled>Ratings</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★★★★">★★★★★</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★★★☆">★★★★☆</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★★☆☆">★★★☆☆</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★☆☆☆">★★☆☆☆</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★☆☆☆☆">★☆☆☆☆</option>
            </select>
        </div>

<div class="row mt-2 mb-2"  id="filters-applied">
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

However, I have noticed that when i delete a banner it will always re-enabled the latest selected option, so i completely restructed the code in case you are interested here is the snippet:

```js
function handleRatingChange(selectElement) {
    createBannerFilter("Rating", selectElement, "ratings-dropdown", "defaultDropDownOption-Rating");
    toggleOption("Rating", selectElement.value, "ratings-dropdown", true, "defaultDropDownOption-Rating");
}

function createBannerFilter(prefix, bannerValue, dropdownId, defaultDropDownOption){
  //Create Banner:
  var banner = document.createElement("div");
  banner.classList.add("badge", "bg-secondary", "m-2", "fs-6", "d-flex", "align-items-center"); // Changed text color and added margin class
  banner.style.width = "auto";
  banner.style.fontWeight = "400";
  if("Rating" === prefix){ 
      banner.innerHTML = prefix + " : " + "<span style='color: #ffc107'> " + bannerValue.value + "</span>";
  }else{
      banner.textContent = prefix + " : " + bannerValue.value;
  }
  // Create Close Button inside Banner
  var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
  closeButton.classList.add("btn", "p-0", "border-0", "ms-2");
  closeButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
  closeButton.setAttribute("aria-label", "Close");
  closeButton.innerHTML = '<span class="fs-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" aria-hidden="true">❌</span>';



  // Close Button Event Listener
  closeButton.addEventListener("click", (function(bannerValue, dropdownId, valueToRemove, prefix, defaultDropDownOption) {
      return function () {
          console.log("close = " + defaultDropDownOption);
          banner.remove();
          toggleOption(prefix, valueToRemove, dropdownId, false, defaultDropDownOption);
      };
  })(bannerValue, dropdownId, bannerValue.value, prefix, defaultDropDownOption));

  banner.appendChild(closeButton);
  document.getElementById("filters-applied").appendChild(banner);
}

function toggleOption(prefix, value, dropdownId, toggle, defaultDropDownOption) {
  var dropdown = document.getElementById(dropdownId);
  var options = dropdown.options;

  // Toggle the specific option
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      if (options[i].value === value && options[i].id !== defaultDropDownOption) {
          if (toggle) {
              options[i].disabled = true;
              manageDefaultSelectOption(prefix, dropdown, value, defaultDropDownOption);
          } else {
              options[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
              manageDefaultSelectOption(prefix, dropdown, value, defaultDropDownOption);
          }
      }
  }                
}

function counter(options){
  var count = -1;
  // Count disabled options
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      if (options[i].hasAttribute("disabled")) {
          count++;
      }
  }

  return count;
}

function manageDefaultSelectOption(prefix, dropdown, value, defaultDropDownOption){
  var defaultOption = document.getElementById(defaultDropDownOption);

  var disabledOptionsCounter = counter(dropdown.options);
  console.log(disabledOptionsCounter);
  // Set the default option based on the number of disabled options
  if (disabledOptionsCounter === 0) {
      dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;
      defaultOption.textContent = prefix;
  } else if (disabledOptionsCounter === 1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < dropdown.options.length; i++) {
          if (dropdown.options[i].hasAttribute("disabled")) {
              dropdown.selectedIndex = i;
              defaultOption.textContent = value;
          }
      }
  } else {
      dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;
      defaultOption.textContent = disabledOptionsCounter + ' options selected';
  }
}
```

```css
/* FILTERS */
option:disabled {
    background-color: #c8c8c8 !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">        
</head>

<div class="col-12">
            <select class="form-select mb-3 ratings-dropdown" id="ratings-dropdown" onchange="handleRatingChange(this)">
                <option id="defaultDropDownOption-Rating" selected disabled>Rating</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★★★★">★★★★★</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★★★☆">★★★★☆</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★★☆☆">★★★☆☆</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★★☆☆☆">★★☆☆☆</option>
                <option style="color: #ffc107" value="★☆☆☆☆">★☆☆☆☆</option>
            </select>
        </div>

<div class="row mt-2 mb-2"  id="filters-applied">
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```